# Javascript scraper find element attribute by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've this simple javascript scraper, used to a local page.

I would find the id attribute of all the "title" class element.

The trouble is that, when i go to print the variable on the screen, the variable (title1) is ever "undefined" and not "xxx" like it must be.

What is wrong?

The local page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div class="title" id="xxx"> xyz</div>
</body>
```

The (partial) code:

```
{ 
    $.get("http://localhost/new.php", function(html) {  
        var title1 = $(html).find(".title").attr("id");
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = title1;
    })
}
```

Comment: test `console.log($(html).get(n))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.title` is a direct element  .. you can use `$(html).filter('.title').attr('id')` or wrap the `.title` div inside another div

```js
var html = '<div class="title" id="xxx"> xyz</div>';
alert($(html).filter('.title').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Wrap div

```js
var html = '<div><div class="title" id="xxx"> xyz</div><div>';
alert($(html).find('.title').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

working example

```js
var html = '<div class="title" id="xxx"> xyz</div>';
var FindId = $(html).filter('.title').attr('id');
$('#1').html(FindId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1"></div>
```

Comment: alert run well. But if i try to do the same with a var and to output in html (like i've done in my example) this not run ^^ (ever "undefinited" and not "xxx")

Comment: @ElDiablo while this code not run and as you said *I would find the id attribute of all the "title" class element.* you need to provide more html which expected to output from php file

Comment: but if "alert" find the id attribute, this part of code is ok. Only i don't understand because if i try to insert the id in a variable, this variable show "undefined".

Comment: @ElDiablo I update my answer with working example .. be sure you already have an element with `id="1"` in your html

Comment: I have. Or it can't show "undefined" :D. I've checked your answer as the most useful. But i don't know how the problem is solved. Simply now, test after test...the code before doesn't runned...run well and show "xxx" instead of "undefined" O_O

Comment: @ElDiablo glad it helped.. Have a great day :-)